# JSoup - Java OutOfMemoryError - using jsoup parser across huge files

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) parser to read HTML files and creating XML file with data extracted. I will be running this code/script across a directory which has several html files (~250k - 300k files) and some of the files are large.

I run into a

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit" or Java heap space
```

error. I have tried running the VM with different `-Xmx` and `-Xms` values, but I keep hitting the same error. I have attached my code snippet.
I am assuming the error occurs when reading a large file. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

```
String target_dir_output = "/test/";
File dir = new File(target_dir);
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for (File f : files) {
    if(f.isFile()) {
        String fileName = f.getName();
        String testValue = null;
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(f, "UTF-8", "");
            Elements metalinks = doc.select("meta[name=testValue]");
            testValue = metalinks.first().attr("content");
            String output = "<data>" + "\n";
            output += "<testValue>" + testValue + "</testValue>" ;
            output += "</data>";
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName + ".xml");
            out.write(output.getBytes());
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: How "large" are the files?

Comment: 1360554953 is the filesize of one of the largest file. Most of the files fall under this category.

Comment: Have you tried running `-Xms` and `-Xmx` together?

Comment: yes. tried that with different ranges from 256m to 8g.

Comment: Most odd. I would image that using both would give you enough to read the files in (e.g. `java -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m`). You should add more context to your question: are you keeping *all* the files in memory?

Comment: You're trying to parse a 1GB HTML file?! You'll probably need at least 4x that to build a DOM tree, possibly more. If possible, look into a stream-based parser that won't have to store the entire tree in memory.

Answer (score 4):

Java has got a limit on the maximal array size your program can allocate. The exact limit is platform specific, but is generally somewhere in between 1 and 2.1 billion elements.

So, when you face the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit, the application at hand is trying to allocate an array larger than your Java Virtual Machine can support.

The error is thrown by the native code within the JVM. It happens before allocating memory for an array, when JVM performs a platform-specific check: whether the allocated data structure is addressable in this platform.

This error is less common than you might initially think. Reason for this is based on the fact that Java arrays are indexed by int. If you recall, maximal positive int in java is 2^31 – 1 = 2,147,483,647. And the platform-specific limits can be really close to this number – for example on my 64bit MB Pro on Java 1.7 I can happily initialize arrays with up to 2,147,483,645, or Integer.MAX_VALUE-2 elements.

Increasing the length of the array by one, to Integer.MAX_VALUE-1 results in the familiar OutOfMemoryError being thrown.

But the limit might not be that high - on 32-bit Linux with OpenJDK 6, you will hit the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit" already when allocating an array with ~1.1 billion elements. To understand the limits of your specific environments, run a small test find it out.